# C# wait for task to complete

Tags: c#

I have a list of methods to execute and some of them are async methods and they take a while to complete. However I need these tasks to finish before the program moves on to the next task as it is doing at the moment because old data is being shown like this.

Any tips on how to do this? These are my tasks. I need the first three tasks to complete their processing before the last two execute.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    getTemp();
    data = new initialData();            

    SetLiveTile();
    liveTile();           
}
```

PS: This is for a windows 8 metro app

The code for the getTemp() is the following. My problem is that I need the value from this method before I execute the rest of the methods but before the value is obtained, the program goes on to execute the SetLiveTile and liveTile methods.

```
 public async void getTemp()
 {
     var weatherService = new WeatherService.GlobalWeatherSoapClient();
     var result = await weatherService.GetWeatherAsync("", "Malta");

     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

     doc.LoadXml(result);

     int pos = doc.InnerText.IndexOf(" F");
     string rem = doc.InnerText.Remove(0, pos + 4);
     string weather = rem.Substring(0, 2);

     temp = int.Parse(weather);
}
```

PS: temp is a global variable

Comment: So which one of these is awaitable ?

Comment: public async void getTemp() and the initialData() makes use of some data obtained from Facebook

Comment: the methods are being called in the main page: public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            await getTemp();
            data = new initialData();
            

            SetLiveTile();
            liveTile();
                   }

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which of your tasks is being run on a different thread, but theoretically when you have a thread, and you want to do something AFTER it finished performing its task, you use the thread.join() method (much like in Java).

Comment: Right. Almost all asynchronous code needs _some_ synchronizing activity.

Comment: in this example you will have to use await, and change the return type of your method from 'void' to 'Task'

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know the events in a Windows Store App, but in Windows Forms you could add an async event handler on load, for example - say that we have these 3 methods that take some time to finish:

```
private Task DoWork() {
    return Task.Delay(3000);
}

private Task DoSomeMoreWork() {
    return Task.Delay(5000);
}

private Task DoEvenMoreWork() {
    return Task.Delay(7000);
}

private async void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // this will take 7 seconds it will execute all the methods at the same time and will resume when all are completed
    await Task.WhenAll(DoWork(), DoSomeMoreWork(), DoEvenMoreWork());

    // will be here when all the methods are done executing
}
```

I hope this gives you an idea at least.

Comment: Basically I need this because I need to display a temperature value and it is taking long to obtain it and the default value is displayed before the task finalizes. I will try this and see what happens.

Comment: I added the method in the question - I'm not managing to have the task complete before it executes the rest

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to check to Barrier class: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537615(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537615%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)